# Why "the" isn't used before significance in this sentence?

Tags: definite-article

An essay on the nature an significance of economics science.

Comment: It should read **on the nature of the significance of** although it could easily be reduced to just **on the significance of**.

Comment: I believe "an" is a typo for "and".  It should read "the nature and significance of economics".  If you inserted an extra "the", it would be "the nature and the significance of economics" - this would be correct, but "the nature and significance" is equally correct and flows better.  The last bit should be either "economics" on its own or "economic science" or "the science of economics" or "economics as a science".

Answer (score 3):

When we are listing multiple items, we don't usually repeat the article if the items are closely related or are considered together as one item.

> [the horse and rider rapidly get to know each other](https://books.google.com/books?id=8C9PAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA314&dq=%22the%20horse%20and%20rider%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs293Dt4_vAhXZRDABHTdaCdkQ6AEwCXoECAcQAg)

> [The knife and fork began to sway and then to dance around the table](https://books.google.com/books?id=ABFV0ZJS8NwC&pg=PT34&dq=%22the%20knife%20and%20fork%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI5pjXt4_vAhXQq1kKHRE0DwMQ6AEwB3oECAUQAg)

> [a chosen distance from the left and right lower control arms](https://books.google.com/books?id=bAnVwcCaznsC&pg=RA1-PA59&dq=%22the%20left%20and%20right%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_65Lrt4_vAhXsp1kKHaaYDTYQ6AEwBHoECAQQAg)

In the title *The Nature and Significance of Economics Science*, both the nature and the significance are the topic of the essay, so they can be considered as one item.